# Varying vertical and horizontal margins in table?

Tags: tables

Here is the table I am after:
[image]

Here is what I currently have:

[image]

See how there are two sub columns I need to have? R.T and Peak Area need to be added in. But I am not sure how to do this.

Here is my code

```
\begin{tabular}{ |p{5cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{TABLE 2: GC RESULTS}} \\
\hline
 Chromatogram Name & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{1-methylcyclohexane} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3-methylcyclohexane} \\
\hline
Pure 1-methylcyclohexane & 2.25 & xxxx & xxxx & xxxx \\
\hline
Pure 3-methylcyclohexane & xxxx & xxxx & 2.10 & xxxx\\
\hline
1:1, v/v mixture of 3 and 1 methylcyclohexane & 2.24 & 117741946 & 2.07 & 
39186503\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: So 'Chromatogram Name' needs to be a `\multirow`!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I propose what I find a more elegant solution, via `booktabs`

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{p{4cm}@{\qquad}rrrr }
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Table of GC Results}}\\
\toprule
\multirow{2}{*}{Chromatogram name}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{1-methylcyclohexene}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{3-methylcyclohexene} \\

&R.T. (min)&Peak Area&R.T. (min)&Peak Area\\
\midrule
Pure 1-methylcyclohexane & 2.25 & xxxx & xxxx & xxxx \\

Pure 3-methylcyclohexane & xxxx & xxxx & 2.10 & xxxx\\

1:1, v/v mixture of 3 and 1 methylcyclohexane & 2.24 & 117741946 & 2.07 & 
39186503\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

The key points are:

1. lose the vertical separators that make the table bulky and not easily readable.
2. lose the `hline` for the same reasons
3. use `multirow` fo the "chromatogram name"
4. use `@{\qquad}` to enhance column separation between the first and the others

Comment: I chose this answer because it is so pretty. Thanks a bunch, this is how I will make tables from now on!

Comment: @MaxwellChandler I invite you to read the documentation of `booktabs` `tabularx` and (if you really need it) `multirow` packages. You can learn a lot!

Comment: I would add a bit of space after the first and second content rows, to make clearer the fact that the last row is one with a description spanning two lines and not tow different rows...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that deliberately does *not* use thick separator lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,caption,multirow}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry} % set width of textblock
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{font=bf,skip=0.2\baselineskip}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\centering
\caption*{Table of GC Results}
\begin{tabular}{|l|C{5.25cm}|*{4}{C{2cm}|}}
\hline
& \multirow{2}{*}{Chromatogram Name}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1-methylcyclohexane} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{3-methylcyclohexane} \\
\cline{3-6}
& & R.T. (min) & Peak Area & R.T. (min) & Peak Area \\
\hline
1 & Pure 1-methylcyclohexane & 2.25 & xxxx & xxxx & xxxx \\
\hline
2 & Pure 3-methylcyclohexane & xxxx & xxxx & 2.10 & xxxx\\
\hline
3 & 1:1, v/v mixture of 3 and 1 methylcyclohexane & 2.24 & 117741946 & 2.07 & 
39186503\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Mico! I would pick both if I could.